# Changing codec of audio but not video?

Tags: video, codec

I want to convert audio tracks of some video I have. These are mkv files, and I want to convert only the audio. The video codec is fine. I attempted to use VLC, but VLC added occasional blocking artifacts to the converted video. I am looking for free software.

Answer (score 3):

[ffmpeg](http://www.ffmpeg.org) will let you re-encode just the audio stream. It is freeware and very flexible.

If you use Linux, it's probably in your distribution's repositories. For Windows, try the [WinFF](http://winff.org/) GUI. I don't know how full featured it is, but the good news is you can run the included binary directly from cmd.exe.

Comment: yes on the ffmpeg thing...seems like i recall ffmpeg.exe being bundled in the klite codec pack if you're already used to the ffmpeg cli arguments

Comment: else [Super](http://www.erightsoft.com/SUPER.html) can do the same